# org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' not supported]

Tags: java, spring, rest, http, spring-mvc

I have a problem when I make a request "http://localhost:8080/main/home" - There was an unexpected error `(type=Internal Server Error, status=500).`

And when a request is "http://localhost:8080/main/add" - There was an unexpected error `(type=Method Not Allowed, status=405).`

My controller class

```
package com.example.transactions.controller;

 import com.example.transactions.model.Transaction;
 import com.example.transactions.repository.TransactionRepository;
 import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

 import java.util.List;

 @RestController
 @RequestMapping("/main")
 public class TransactionController {

    @Autowired (required = false)
    private TransactionRepository transactionRepository;


    @GetMapping("/home")
    public List<Transaction> getAll(){
        return transactionRepository.findAll();
    }

    @PostMapping("/add")
    public Transaction addTransaction (@RequestParam Transaction transaction ){
        return transactionRepository.save(transaction);
    }
}
```

My Repository class

```
package com.example.transactions.repository;

import com.example.transactions.model.Transaction;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;


@Repository
public interface TransactionRepository extends JpaRepository<Transaction,Integer> {
}
```

Application.properties

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jab.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/oracle
spring.datasource.username=sys
spring.datasource.password=chingishan
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
```

Comment: These are actually two questions in one.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is only a `@PostMapping` for `/main/add`, your request to `http://localhost:8080/main/add`, which is likely GET, is not supported.

As to the 500 for the other endpoint: This means your code throws a `RuntimeException` that is not handled. You should see a stack trace. Apart from that, the question has insufficient detail.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your first issue: error 500.

Spring is failing to inject your dependency: TransactionRepository

It's not a good practice set Autowired as required = false, because Spring will leave the bean unwired if the dependency is not resolved and than causing the 500 error when you call "http://localhost:8080/main/home".

Please share your app logs and also remove this require false. Your app will start failing during start up time, so you can get the proper error.

Comment: While this may be a possible cause: What makes you so sure?

Comment: I did what you said
//////////                                                                                                          Field transactionRepository com.example.transactions.controller.TransactionController required a bean of type 'com.example.transactions.repository.TransactionRepository' that could not be found.

Comment: @MichaelPiefel, removing "required = false" will revel the real error. It's not the cause.

Comment: Field transactionRepository in com.example.transactions.controller.TransactionController required a bean of type 'com.example.transactions.repository.TransactionRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
 - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.transactions.repository.TransactionRepository' in your configuration.

Comment: @Монгол, that is 500 error cause. Your controller is not finding your repository. Adding required = false back will just postpone your issue. Is there any other log detail to share?

Comment: @Монгол, have you enabled JPA in your dependencies? "spring-boot-starter-data-jpa". Another option is to force a package scan but not seems to be the issue here: @SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={"com.example.transactions"})

Comment: @Ezequiel Thanks I solved this problem, now I have a lot more but I hope I will solve it

Answer (score -1):

Please check your **application.properties** file configuration

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.data.jpa.repositories.enabled=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/oracle
spring.datasource.username=sys
spring.datasource.password=chingishan
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
```

check here. it should be RequestBody for the Object and ReqestParams used for name-value pair.

```
 @PostMapping("/add")
    public Transaction addTransaction (@RequestBody Transaction transaction ){
        return transactionRepository.save(transaction);
    }
```

get the transaction data and set it to your entity and then call the repository save method.